# Why does pyqt5 app report "Could not create collator: 4" when creating a QFileDialog set to DontUseNativeDialog?

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

I have a program that I run and when I click the top button it prints to the console "Could not create collator: 4". The file dialog box still opens and I can still select a file. When I click open it reports the messgage again.

How can I elemenate this from happening. I know that if i don't use

```
opts = opts | QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
```

then it will work BUT I get a dialog box that is windows/linux/etc specific and it looks off form the qt window look.

```
import time
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGridLayout, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon      

class Main_Widget(QWidget, QObject):

    sigStop = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("WonderCloud Main Window")
        Main_Window = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(Main_Window)
        self.resize(800, 400)


        self.fileDia = FileDia()
        self.btnSelectConfigFile = QPushButton()
        #self.btnSelectConfigFile.clicked.connect(self.start_worker)
        ##self.btnSelectConfigFile.clicked.connect(self.fileDia.selectFileNameDialog)
        self.btnSelectConfigFile.clicked.connect(self.selectFileNameDialog)
        self.btnSelectConfigFile.setText("Select Configuration File")

        self.btnSetConfigFileAndCont = QPushButton()
        #self.btnSetConfigFileAndCont.clicked.connect(self.start_worker)
        self.btnSetConfigFileAndCont.setText("Set Configuration And Continue")

        Main_Window.addWidget(self.btnSelectConfigFile)
        Main_Window.addWidget(self.btnSetConfigFileAndCont)

    def selectFileNameDialog(self):    
        opts = QFileDialog.Options()
        #options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        opts = opts | QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        #fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=opts)
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=opts)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    window = Main_Widget()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the value contained within `opts`? (This will tell readers what other options are set by default on you install/platform)

Comment: This indicates that there is something screwy with your locale. The status code 4 = U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR ("The requested file cannot be found"). So Qt is trying to identify your locale, but fails because something is missing on your system. Not exactly sure what, though. The relevant source code is [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.11/src/corelib/tools/qcollator_icu.cpp#L63).